# Google deployment manager elastic search node rescaling issue

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When I try to change the machine type of an elastic search node by editing it via cloud console the node is lost, i.e. I get connection refused on port 9200. When I try to do the same via deployment manager config update the node simply won't update, and I get the error:

> message: u"Unexpected response from resource of type
>   compute.v1.instance: RESOURCE_NOT_READY

Is it at all possible to change the machine type of a single node or to add more nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the machine type of an instance in the TERMINATED state.
Details [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance).

Comment: That was my first option. After node restart I can not connect to elastic search anymore on that node.

Comment: Apparently ES doesn't start on its own after a reboot: you need to create a service https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html